# How to keep the states of views? Should one view have only one ViewModel?

Tags: winforms, design-patterns, webforms, mvp

I have two forms,

1. one main form which has a grid view showing a list of type `AaaViewModel`.
2. and one subform which will pop up after click a row in the main form. It will show some data from the row clicked in the main form and a grid view with a list of type `BbbViewModel` related to the row clicked.

How do I keep the states of the main form? Should it be

```cs
interface IMainForm { IEnumerable<AaaViewModel> state; ....}
```

or should it be put in the presenter class? Should another ViewModel be defined as `IEnumerable<AaaViewModel>` for main form?

BTW, how should the ViewModel of the subform be defined? Should it use two view model `AaaViewModel` and `BbbViewModel`? Or should it be combined.

```cs
class SubformViewModel
{
     public AaaViewModel Main { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<BbbViewModel> Sub { get; set; }
}
```

Or I don't need to have AaaViewModel in the subform if I only need a couple of fields from the main form?

```cs
class SubformViewModel
{
     public int Field1 { get; set; }
     public string Field2 { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<BbbViewModel> Sub { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Which route did you take?